# How to debug a CentOS machine that stops responding periodically?

Tags: centos, freeze, crash, centos-7

I have a CentOS 7 machine that would freeze every few days. The `kdump service` is running, but no crash dump file is created.
The syslog is also not much help. For instance, in `/var/log/messages`, the latest such freeze is at line 1091020 (the lines that follow are the reboot that I started by pressing the power button, as the system is unresponsive at that stage, including to ssh):

```
1091015 Jun  8 17:20:17 drishti env: 2020-06-09 00:20:17,967 TRACE spool dir at /local/raid0/jsonar/data/gateway/spool
1091016 Jun  8 17:20:17 drishti env: 2020-06-09 00:20:17,968 TRACE spool dir at /local/raid0/jsonar/data/gateway/spool/0
1091017 Jun  8 17:20:17 drishti env: 2020-06-09 00:20:17,968 TRACE spool dir at /local/raid0/jsonar/data/gateway/spool/0/spool
1091018 Jun  8 17:20:17 drishti env: 2020-06-09 00:20:17,968 TRACE spool dir at /local/raid0/jsonar/data/gateway/spool/3
1091019 Jun  8 17:20:17 drishti env: 2020-06-09 00:20:17,968 TRACE spool dir at /local/raid0/jsonar/data/gateway/spool/3/spool
1091020 Jun  8Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti journal: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 1.5G, trying to leave 2.3G free of 15.6G available → current limit 1.5G).
1091021 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
1091022 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
1091023 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
1091024 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
1091025 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Mar 31 23:36:51 UTC 2020
1091026 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=c7039987-532d-4b03-b706-0b40b9aa50d4 ro crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet crashkernel=128M
1091027 Jun  9 09:17:59 drishti kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

Can you suggest approaches to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working with a physical computer and not a Virtual Machine (VM). This kind of intermittent failures can be difficult to diagnose. To generalize you may have a software problem or a hardware problem.

**Hardware**

How old is the hardware on this computer? Even if the parts of new, a hardware problem in the RAM, CPU, Motherboard, or Power Supply would result in this kind of reboot.

- The easiest one to check is the RAM. You want to run memtest86 on the computer. [Here are some instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/), you want to scroll down to Option #2. Run memtest86 overnight, or for 24 hours to give it a chance to test multiple times. If there are no errors or the system does not reboot; this means the probability your RAM causing the problem is low: but not zero!
- The Power Supply (PSU) is the easiest to replace. If you have a spare PSU you could replace your current one with a spare; alternatively you could spend the money and buy a new PSU. The idea here is to swap out a component, but swap them out **one at a time**. This isolates what could be wrong.
- CPU temperature: there is a chance you are overtaxing the system and the CPU temperature is high enough that it is causing the system to reboot. Is there a pattern to these reboots: that is when the CPU is crunching something?
- Did you install new hardware? Is there something new you recently put into this computer, such as a new video card? There is the chance that a new piece of equipment in an older machine may be 'overtaxing' the existing hardware.

  - Example: You have a PSU that only puts out 400W. That works fine for years but then you put in a brand new video card that requires lots of power. Over time your PSU's power output will drop a bit as it ages, and a new card that draws lots of power will overtax the PSU, resulting in  power load higher than the PSU can handle, resulting in these reboots.

**Software**

- If you can bot this computer using a USB stick, you could boot into a Live Linux distribution or something like System Rescue CD. This works best if you do not need your computer for your work. You then leave this system running for a few days untouched with the different OS. The point is if you do not have a hardware failure, and the system does **not** spontaneously reboot, you can conclude that there may be something wrong with the software on the machine.
- A good diagnostic program is `dstat`. You want to install it with

  - `yum install dstat`
- Then run it as root. Here is a command you can use to

  - `dstat -tcdrgilmns --output /var/log/dstat.csv --noupdate 5`

From: https://www.rootusers.com/my-top-3-linux-commands-for-logging-problems/

> This will run dstat with -tcdrgilmns, below is what each option does –
>   see the man page for full information as there are many more options,
>   use the ones you need.

```
-t: Time – enables timestamps on the logs, very useful when logging at logs later
-c: CPU stats (system, user, idle, wait, hardware interrupt, software interrupt)
-d: Disk stats (read, write)
-r: I/O request stats (read, write)
-g: Page stats (page in, page out)
-i: Interrupt stats
-l: Load stats (1 minute average, 5 minute average, 15 minute average)
-m: Memory stats (used, buffers, cache, free)
-n: Network stats (received, sent)
-s: Swap stats (used, free)
```

> --output is specifying that the output will be logged to /var/log/dstat.csv
>
> --noupdate will mean that dstat will not refresh until 5 seconds have passed, otherwise dstat will still actually refresh every 1 second, it
>   just wont be written to the log file. 5 also means that the result of
>   the dstat query will be logged every 5 seconds, you can change this to
>   suit your needs however generally.

Your goal is to log the system stats with `dstat` in to a file, and after the computer spontaneously reboots, look in the file and investigate the stats. Is the RAM filling up? Is there inordinately high CPU usage? Keep in mind, if there is nothing out of the ordinary, that may not mean the problem is not in software: it's just that you're not logging what is causing the problem.